# Accesing Windows 8 Share from linux client

Tags: samba, windows-8.1

I'm trying to access a windows 8 share from fedora.

The scenario is like this:

In the Windows 8 PC, under the user folder, i share a folder, allowing access to the same user. The account is a Microsoft account (not local).

When I try to access from the network with samba, I'm promted with user, workgroup and password, and have tried a lot of different combinations, but none seems to work!

Which is the username that is efectively allowed to access the share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved It!

If you have a windows live account, say test@hotmail.com, you should fill the fields like this:

username: test

domain/workgroup: hotmail.com

password: your hotmail password

If you haven't got a separate field for the domain/workgroup enter *hotmail.com/test* as the username.

That's it!

Comment: Wow took me forever to figure this out! Was trying to access my Windows 8 machine from Mint Linux and tried MicrosoftAccount\<live_id_username>, instead of the login <computer_name>\<username> as in previous versions of Windows first since that usually works with Apple machines connecting to Windows 8. Anyways tried what you said above and didn't work. Well it did help me get it to work though because using live.com instead of hotmail.com did work!

Comment: This even works for a Microsoft account that isn't using one of Microsoft's own domains, like:

john@example.org